Generating mermaid-based diagrams using ChatGPT
I'm creating a feature for a plugin I created for VSCode, where I use ChatGpt (gpt-4) to explain the source code (preferably Dart) in the form of flowcharts, using the Mermaid markup language.
Most of the times when I generated the diagram, ChatGpt made some small error in the mermaid language rules, which broke the visualization. Usually these errors happen when it tries to concatenate some text that has some special character.
If anyone can help with tips on what I can try to do to solve, or at least reduce the chance of these small errors, I would be very grateful.
{
    model: model,
    messages: [
        {
            role: 'system',
            content: `You are a mermaid generator. Create a state chart using mermaid from the provided source code. ` +
                'Do not use any quote marks or any special characters that is not supported by mermaid version 11.3.0. ' +
                'Do not include ```mermaid or ``` code blocks, Just provide the Mermaid code for the diagram.' +
                'Do not provide comments about the code.' +
                `
                Example of mermaid code:
                
                flowchart TD
                A[Christmas] -->| Get money| B(Go shopping)
                B--> C{ Let me think }
                C-->| One | D[Laptop]
                C-->| Two | E[iPhone]
                C-->| Three | F[Car]

                use the documentation as rules reference https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/flowchart.html
            `,
        },
        {
            role: 'system',
            content: 'provide context of you code and the source code you want to generate a diagram from',
        },
        {
            role: 'user',
            content: aditionalUserPrompt + "\n" + sourceCode
        },
    ],
    n: 1
};

I tried several prompts and arrived at this current one which has a certain stability.
Example Video
